# Disable or hide a parameter in sql server reporting services

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have two parameters 1>Type 2>Start date. there are 3 values for types 1.A 2.b 3.C , I want to disable or hide the start date when b is selected in the type parameter and allow selection of a date in start date when A or C are selected.

Comment: I think it is doubtful that it would be possible.  Although you can run code in SSRS, the parameters, etc. don't have any code options (not talking about expressions).  You could use a linked report and name the report something else and then just specific whether the parameter is disabled or not.

Comment: Please explain how to link reports , some elaboration would help

Comment: Somewhat dependant on the version, but on the report properties, you will see a button that says "Create Linked Report", which creates a link (either in the same folder or elsewhere) and then lets you redefine some of the settings, like parameters.  Useful if you are using it to manage permissions, or have a whole lot of linked reports, each for a branch - in their own folder, etc.  You get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joel,

To achieve this you can use the idea of Cascading Parameters. In your case the dataset you use to define the Start Date parameter will itself be conditional upon the value of the Type parameter. Let me illustate with an example:

I have defined a Dataset for the Type parameter as follows:

```
SELECT 'A' AS TypeParameter UNION SELECT 'B' UNION SELECT 'C';
```

This will give a list of A, B and C as you require.

I have defined a second Dataset for the Start Date parameter as follow:

```
WITH StartDates AS
(
/* All dates for Type A*/
SELECT
    DateKey
,   CAST(FullDateAlternateKey AS varchar) AS FullDateText
,   'A' AS TypeParameter
FROM
    DimDate
UNION
SELECT
    0
,   '*'
,   'A'
UNION
/* Default option for Type B*/
SELECT
    0
,   '*'
,   'B'
UNION
/* All dates for Type C*/
SELECT
    DateKey
,   CAST(FullDateAlternateKey AS varchar) AS FullDateText
,   'C' AS TypeParameter
FROM
    DimDate
UNION
SELECT
    0
,   '*'
,   'C'
)
SELECT
DateKey
,   FullDateText
FROM
StartDates
WHERE
TypeParameter = @TypeParameter
```

Basically the idea here is to create a three column Dataset. The first column contains a list of date Keys (in this example I have taken them from a Date table found in the AdventureWorks DW database). The second column contains the date you want users to see. The third column contains only those Type Parameter values you want Start Dates to be available for. In this case Types A and C. So each date appears twice, once for Type A and once for Type C. Each Type option has a default value (Key 0 and text *).

In the WHERE clause I filter according to the value of the Type parameter chosen by the user. If they choose Type A or Type C then a full list of dates ia available (including the default option). If they choose Type B then only the default option is available.

Although the Start Date is not disabled or hidden, no Start Date can be chosen other than the default.

This should achieve what you want.

I hope it helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Ash

Comment: Glad to hear it Joel. Would you do me a kindness and mark it as the accepted solution? Thanks, Ash

Comment: kindness done! do pardon me for not marking it before